# Add new property to state object from a form component with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a form that adds new articles. I need to create another form that triggers when I click on a created article and add a property "keyword" to the article state and display it. I tried to do something but I am kinda stuck.

Form.jsx component that adds the article/s:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { v1 as uuidv1 } from 'uuid';

import { ADD_ARTICLE } from '../constants/action-types';

const Form = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target
    setTitle(value);
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const id = uuidv1();
    dispatch({ type: ADD_ARTICLE, payload: { id, title } });
    setTitle('');
  } 

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <label htmlFor='title'>Title</label>
        <input
          type='text'
          className='form-control'
          id='title'
          value={title}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <input className='btn btn-success btn-lg' type='submit' value='SAVE' />
    </form>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

List.jsx component where the articles are displayed:

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import KeywordForm from './KeywordForm.jsx';

import { fetchArticles } from '../thunk';

const List = () => {
  const [showForm,setShowForm]=useState(false);

  const articles = useSelector(state => state.articles);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();



  const displayForm=()=>{
   setShowForm(!showForm)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchArticles);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    <ul className='list-group list-group-flush'>
      {articles.map(article => (
        <li className='list-group-item' key={article.id} onClick={displayForm}> 
          {article.title}  
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
    <div>

    {showForm && (
        <KeywordForm />
      )}
    </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default List;
```

Here i added a state that displays the KeywordForm component when I click an article.

KeywordForm.jsx component,this is the one that I created to add the keyword:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch ,useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { ADD_KEYWORD } from '../constants/action-types';

const KeywordForm = ({id,title}) => {
    
    const [keyword,setKeyword]=useState('');
    const articles = useSelector(state => state.articles);
    const dispatch=useDispatch();

    console.log(articles)


    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { value } = e.target
        setKeyword(value);
      }
  
      const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        
        
      }  

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <label htmlFor='keyword'>Keyword</label>
          <input
            type='text'
            className='form-control'
            id='keyword'
            value={keyword}
            onChange={handleChange}
            
            
          />
        </div>
        <input className='btn btn-success btn-lg' type='submit' value='SAVE' />
      </form>
    );
  }
  
  export default KeywordForm;
```

reducers.js

```
const initialState = {
  articles: []
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch(type) {
    case ADD_ARTICLE: {
      return {...state, 
        articles: [...state.articles,payload]
      };
    }

    case ADD_KEYWORD: {
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        articles: state.articles.concat(payload)
      });
    }

    case ARTICLES_RETRIEVED: {
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        articles: state.articles.concat(payload)
      });
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default rootReducer;
```

actions.js

```
import { ADD_ARTICLE, ARTICLES_RETRIEVED,ADD_KEYWORD } from '../constants/action-types';

const addArticle = (payload) => {
  return { type: ADD_ARTICLE, payload };
}

const addKeyword = (payload) => {
  return { type: ADD_KEYWORD, payload };
}

const articlesRetrieved = (payload) => {
  return { type: ARTICLES_RETRIEVED, payload };
}

export { addArticle, articlesRetrieved,addKeyword };
```

What should i add to my reducers/actions to make this work? My idea is that i have to somehow pass the id of the article clicked and then in the reducer find it's index or something and check it with the payload.id .

Comment: Your add keyword reducer is adding an entire article to your state.  It should be modifying an existing article by adding a keyword to it.

Comment: @LindaPaiste And how can i do that exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to modify an existing article in the state and a keyword to it (can there be an array of keywords, or just one?).  In order to do that, your action payload will need to contain both the `keyword` and the `id` of the article that it belongs to.

Your reducer will find the article that matches the `id` and replace it with a copied version that has the `keyword` added to it.

```
case ADD_KEYWORD: {
  return {
     ...state,
     articles: state.articles.map(article => 
        // find the article to update
       article.id === payload.id ? 
       // update it
       { ...article, keyword: payload.keyword } : 
       // otherwise return the original
       article
  }
}
```

This is easier to do with the official [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) because you can modify the draft state directly and you don't need to worry about mutations.